# What is Model in MvvM

Tags: mvvm

I have a window with four textbox and one combo. So my Model is like this

```
Public string FirstName{get;set;}

Public string LastName{get;set;}

Public int Age{get;set;}

Public string Status{get;set;}
```

It is Right or not

And Model is one to one correspond with elements in User Interface.

I am right or not

Comment: It's not required that your model has to correspond 1:1 with your UI components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Model" in MVVM do not describe an object, but a layer. Generally everything that's not presentation (ViewModel layer) or UI (View Layer) falls into the category of Model.

Usually there are two additional layers: Domain/Business Layer and one or more Infrastructure layers (Data Access for example). In the domain layer you have you domain models and (domain) services as well as definitions of repositories (interfaces only).

The repositories gets implemented in the infrastructure layer, so your domain is unaware of their implementation.

Usually you should only pass domain models to your ViewModels, except for maybe simple CRUD operations where you directly display data and edit it, with no business logic enforced on them.

You shouldn't bind your domain or data access models to the View, as it has many side effects (memory leaks in WPF, your views now depend on domain/data access models, it's not refactory safe. Refactory works for classes, but not for properties bound in XAML).

Answer (score 0):

Questions 1: Yes, it is right!

The model is the representation of the data(domain) object you want to deal with.

Questions 2: No, this is not necessarly true. 
More important: the model keeps the information and not the behavior attached to it. The User interface usually consists of information and behaviors.